# IE8 XmlHttpRequest Debugging

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest, ie-developer-tools

I am looking for some way to elegantly inspect XmlHttpRequests in IE8. I wouldn't mind a plugin or an external program. I have yet to find anything that works nearly as well as Firebug.

I have already tried Julien Couvreur's bookmark debugger, but it did not seem to work with Prototype. [Julien's Script](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000291.html)

Comment: What exactly are u trying to look at in the Request?

Comment: Client request headers, server response headers, payload, request state, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fiddler is the main tool for Request Response Debuggin in IE... ( FireBug in FireFox )

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: I have used Fiddler before and completely forgot about it. For those browsing this question it snag's IE's network connection and acts like a local proxy routing all IE traffic through it. This is probably as close to Firebug's offerings as one can get.

Comment: The mixture of IE Developer Tools (F12 in IE8 ) and fiddler you get far more support than in the old IE 6 days... 
Still wishing for built-in DOM viewer like FireBug... ( makes writing JS far more easy )

Comment: This answer just saved me hours of tedious debugging.  Fiddler showed me that in one case my server wasn't sending HTTP headers with its XML response. FF and Safari didn't care, but IE7, IE8 and Chrome barfed with no clue what was going on.  Thanks Stackoverflow!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you retrieve the output, and write to the console directly?  For example, if using a jQuery $.post:

```
$.post("posturl", data, function(output){
     console.log(output);
}
```

I found this worked somewhat for me while working with IE.  But I like firebug best for this; the output is easy to inspect.